# Android: How to pass additional object reference to a custom view

Tags: android, object, view, custom-controls, ondraw

Currently I have a custom view:

```
public class MyView extends View {

  public MyView(Context c, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);

  }
    ....
    ....
}
```

Now, I want to access an object that is not Android related, say a database connection, how do i do that? 
My current solution is to do the following

```
public class MyView extends View {
  DBConnection connection;

  public MyView(Context c, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);

  }
    ....
    ....
  public void setDBConnection(DBConnection c)
       this.connection = c;
  } 

  public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    this.connection.ensureUser();
     ...
     ....
  }
```

My question is that is there a better way to do this? Currently I need to set (via setter) to ensure that the object that is going to be used in the `MyView` class is set, above code snippet works but I don't know if this is the elegant / popular approach?

I am thinking to pass the object via the constructor, but I can't do that, because Android only calls the `MyView(Context c, AttributeSets attrs)` constructor, it won't call the version if I have `MyView(Context c, AttributeSets attrs, DBConnection db)` one.

please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I come across situations like this, I tend to take the approach of injecting the displayable data after the view is created. So, if your view needed a string of text to display, you inject that string or the object the string is pulled from during your activities creation by looking up the `View` using `findViewById` and then calling the appropriate setter.

As to "is there a better way to do this", I would be nervous about passing a `dbconnection` into a view class. It doesn't pass the "smell" test and seems like you are leaking your logic into your view. It would make more sense to me to say, give your view a `Cursor` or some object you've filled in inside your `Activity`. This prevents building custom views that are tightly coupled to a very specific use/scenario.

On the other hand, you'll have to decide how reusable you want the view to be. It might be that quick and dirty is the appropriate tact for this particular project.

Comment: Hi Nick, thanks for your reply. actually the db connection was just an example.  can you gibe me an example of using injection?  i am kind of skeptical of using injection....i mean it might work, but i still don't think it is the ONLY other way of doing this...because injection , say Guice, is something that is required.  and i don't think it is unusual that you need to pass something (whether it is an object or just a simple string) to a custom view...

Comment: Sorry, i mean injection more generically. When you talk about passing something in the constructor or using a setter, it just means that the view is getting its data by someone "inserting" or "injecting" it rather than having logic to find its data internally. Consider this, if you pass a List<Strings> to a view which displays those strings, it doesn't have much logic to it. If instead, you pass a database connection, then the view has to contain code to use that database connection to find the data it needs. Typically, the latter type with internal code like that are less reusable.